# Selecting rows and copying to columns

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to copy a specific row and for example I want to select jake's scores in this image

[image]

now I want to copy them to be like this

[image: here is the desired output]

I asked the community and they helped me a lot and I came up with this piece of code:

```
Sub main()    
    Dim rangeSrc As Range, range1 As Range

    Set rangeSrc = Application.InputBox("Select src Range", "select src range", Type:=8) 'type 8 = range
    Set range1 = Application.InputBox("select des range", "select des range", Type:=8)

    If Not rangeSrc Is Nothing And Not range1 Is Nothing Then
        rangeSrc.Copy range1      
    End If     
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there:

1. You need to `.PasteSpecial Transpose:=True` to transpose your data.
2. I inserted an error handling so the user is able to press the cancel button.
3. I renamed your variables since `range1` is not a good variable name. Using meaningful names makes it much easier to read and maintain your code.

So you end up with …

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub main()
    On Error Resume Next 'don't error on cancel button
    Dim rngSource As Range
    Set rngSource = Application.InputBox("Select src Range", "select src range", Type:=8) 'type 8 = range

    Dim rngDest As Range
    Set rngDest = Application.InputBox("select des range", "select des range", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0 're-activate error reporting

    If Not rngSource Is Nothing And Not rngDest Is Nothing Then
        rngSource.Copy
        rngDest.PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    End If
End Sub
```

If you only want to paste values without formatting, use …

```
rngDest.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
```

See [Range.PasteSpecial method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial) and [xlPasteType enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype) for more information.

Comment: god bless you ! and thanks for the advice it is way better than my original code!